# Algorithm for a name search [School Project]

Tags: database, algorithm, search, pseudocode

I need help with making a algorithm (Pseudocode) which will search for a student from the list of students. the students details are in a database and I'm not sure how to go about this.
So far , I've come up with

```
BEGIN StudentSearch (KeyInput, Firstname [ ] , Surname [ ] , Mark [ ]) :
rownum = 1
IF KeyInput length = 0:
    Display alphabetical order of names

OTHERWISE: 
WHILE NOT EOF:
    If KeyInput = FirstName
        Display FirstName [i] , Surname [i] , Mark [i] in Row rownum
        rownum+=1
```

How should I go about sorting the names based on matching characters or considering the data types and structures.

Comment: Have you considered SQL and wildcards?

Comment: Is this pseudocode? The code looks like pseudocode but it's not tagged with pseudocode. *Edit*: The lack of [mcve](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) makes it difficult to provide an accurate answer.

Comment: @TrebuchetMS yeah It is pseudocode, sorry about that.

Comment: @saketk21 I have no knowledge of either so no. We haven't begun or will be writing the actual codes until next year. This is just the algorithm in pseudocode (sorry if it wasn't clear)